# Pulling in random profile pics from Linkedin API

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

I'm making an iPhone app which needs to pull in random Linkedin profile pictures (that are publicly accessible). I could simply send requests for random profile ids, but it seems very inefficient. Is there a more effective way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LinkedIn API is not designed for searching done by non-authenticated users (nor random searching). You could theoretically do the following:
1) Authorize the user using the app
2) Do a search for a random string as that user
3) Display the profile picture for one of the results

The Terms of Use doesn't allow you to create a "master user" and access the API without authenticating each user who uses the application.